# AudioRecord get stream volume

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to read data and then send it to another stream. First of all, I want to check if it works. The problem is, getstreamVolume will not work here and I don't know which method I should use. I have this code:

```
        audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC
                , SAMPLE_RATE
                , AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO
                , AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
                , intBufferSize);

        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC
                , SAMPLE_RATE
                , AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO
                , AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
                , intBufferSize
                , AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        audioTrack.setPlaybackRate(SAMPLE_RATE);

        audioRecord.startRecording();
        audioTrack.play();

        while (true){

            audioRecord.read(AudioData, 0, AudioData.length);

            for (int i = 0; i < AudioData.length; i++){
                AudioData[i] = (short) Math.min (AudioData[i], Short.MAX_VALUE);
            }

            audioTrack.setVolume(0.3f);
            audioTrack.write(AudioData, 0, AudioData.length);
        }
```

How can I check the volume of input data in db? Or should I use Audio Manager?

Comment: I'm sorry, but why the interval is [-.6, 0.5]? The idea is to check the volume of input data and decide whether I need to send it to another device or not.

Comment: I also thought that -1 and 1 are normalized values in db..

Comment: Ok. So I go back to question: what should I do to check the input volume?

Comment: Yes, Matt, I think you helped me. If I have some problems, i will update the question. Thank you and sorry for stupid questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum volume of an audio stream can only be calculated across several samples; it is the maximum absolute value encountered in the stream:

```
double[] samps = [0, -.5, 0, 0.5, 0, -.75, 0]

double max = 0;
for ( samp : samps ) {

    if ( abs(samp) > max) {
        max = abs(samp);
    }
}
```

The maximum *volume* for the above audio sample would be *.75*, (or at `-1.25dB`); this means you can effectively amplify the signal by *1.33* and not lose any information; the output stream would rise back up to `0dB` and become:

```
[0, -.67, 0, .67, 0, -1, 0]
```

Comment: I know. I set 0.3 for output. And I also need to know the volume in db of the input stream.

Comment: Thank you, Matt.